# Activate/Deactivate action on Product list

Tags: trigger

In the Product list table you have an Activate/Deactivate action links (the left column).
When I click these the action does not fire the On Update trigger I have.
If I implement a custom button to change the Active field the trigger is fired.

This is my trigger definition:

```
trigger ProductTriggers on Product2 (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete) {

}
```

Has anyone ran into the same problem?
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed this is happening in my dev org as well. It also looks like others are running into this issue as well. Stolen from a [link on the Developer Boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Product-after-update-trigger-and-Product-Activation/td-p/449481) by sfdcfox,

> I've confirmed this behavior. It's calling the standard edit
>   controller ( /{!Product2.Id}/e?act=0&retURL... ) that does not have
>   the usual save=x parameter (where x is any value, but usually the word
>   Save). It seems to bypass all validation, workflow, and trigger logic.
>   Nothing shows up in the debug logs at all. I suspect that this is a
>   bug, and you should report it to Technical Support.

sfdcfox also posts a workaround to solve this:

> ...if you
>   override the product2.edit action with a Visualforce component, you
>   can perform the update in your custom code, which fires your trigger
>   correctly. This is only a shortterm solution, as it introduces a CSRF
>   attack, but is no worse than the original problem, which is also CSRF
>   vulernerable. Alternatively, have the edit page offer them a chance to
>   cancel or confirm the action so you yourself prevent the CSRF attack.